# How to protect a form from a manual change

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I put a hidden field `Id` in the html form, in order to use it to find the user I want to edit, I can change that value with browser inspector and when I submit the form it will modify the wrong user.

How to protect such thing?

Comment: If a user is able to alter an entity that they do not have permission to alter, then you have a serious security issue that is more important than worrying about stopping someone altering a hidden value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632626/how-to-detect-hidden-field-tampering

Answer (score 2):

- Always assume that the user can do this.
- Always validate in server-side code that the user is allowed to do what the user is attempting to do before doing it.

That's basically it.  If the user manually modifies client-side values or manually crafts a POST with their own values, one of two things should happen:

- If the user is allowed to perform that action, the action is performed and the server responds as usual.
- If the user is not allowed to perform that action, the server responds with an error.

What would happen if the user requested through the site's normal functionality to edit that record?  That's exactly what should happen if the user tries to do it manually.

So essentially in the controller action method where the edit is performed, check the permissions to make sure the user it allowed to perform that edit first.  Don't rely on doing this *before* the action method is invoked or assume that the view you returned is the one from which the action method is invoked.  In each individual action method you check permissions as needed for just that action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MVC Security Extensions project https://mvcsecurity.codeplex.com.

Say the field you want to protect is Id...

On you controller post method add:

```
[ValidateAntiModelInjection("Id")]
```

Within your view add:

```
@Html.AntiModelInjectionFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```

On post your Id field will be validated.

Comment: You should still ensure that if the user is not allowed to perform that action, the server responds with an error. Although this solution is good, gives us defence in depth, it should not be used alone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can protect the user from editing a form (the point of a form is to be edited). And you cant really stop them from editing javascirpt objects. Thats also plain and accessable by the browser. But what you can do is store the ids in the session. This way you can check everytime you get a request if the id from the form matches the id from the session.